# Other directive like ng-init or event like stateChangeStart that trigger for specific route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I use angular.js and ionic for building mobile application.

I use **ng-init** for my view initialize but it's triggered only **first time**  and if I change route (state url) and back again it's not triggerd.

I am very new to angular and I've searched a lot, **I'm looking for a directive that will be triggerd each time state change to specific route and view will load.** Something like stateChangeStart but only for specific route.

Comment: you can listen event  routechangeStart

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but routechangeStart triggered when I leave current route to the other while I'm looking for an event that will be triggerd when I enter a route. Something like stateChangeStart but only for specific route.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a directive for it ,You can do it with the event

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 

    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
       if(toState=="login"){
          <--Do your task here-->
         }
    }
```

Here i select login as my state to perform the task you can select according to your requirement.